# Confusion about the signs we use in Faraday's law for emf

Tags: electromagnetism, conventions

While reading griffiths, I came accross the definition of emf, which is given by

$$ \epsilon = -\int_a^b \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{l} = \oint \vec{f} \cdot d \vec{l} $$

Here we use $\vec{E} + \vec{f} = 0$ in a ideal conductor (since $\sigma \rightarrow \infty$). Here $\vec{E}$ is the force per unit charge due to the electric field and $\vec{f}$ is some force of any other nature.

I understand how the definite integral has been extended to a closed loop integral, but to my confusion is this definition of the emf, although I have an idea of how it works, I am not sure and would prefer some clarification.

In a time varying magnetic field a force, electric but non-conservative in nature is induced, which moves charges along the loop to flow current, and since this is a non-conservative field it is different from $\vec{E}$ used in the previous definition, and the emf is now given as

$$ \epsilon = \oint \vec{E_f} \cdot d\vec{l} = -\frac{d\phi}{dt} $$

Here there is no negative sign in emf as a line integral since the force $E_f$ now counts as a force with origins other than the conservative electric field. Is this correct? I asked my teacher about this he insisted there will remain a negative sign in the latter definition.

I would also appreciate if someone could add something more I may be missing aside from the clarification.